# run ng-serve successfully without "find module 'ng2-date-countdown'" error

Tags: node.js, angularjs

I need your help please for this issue.In fact I have upgraded the angular-cli and nodejs  versions in my system then I got this error when trying to run my project:

[image]

[image]

I am using:
[image]

How can I run ng-serve successfully without this error.Thanks for help.

Comment: did you import the module inside @NgModule?

Answer (score 1):

You need to insert the module in @NgModule:

```
import { CountdownModule } from "ng2-date-countdown";

@NgModule({
   declarations: [
     AppComponent
   ],
   imports: [
     BrowserModule,
     CountdownModule
   ],
   bootstrap: [AppComponent]
 })
```

Also stop the server and then run ng-serve again after that.

Comment: did you stop the server (Ctrl+C on ng-serve terminal) and then did the ng-serve command again?

Comment: yes Sir I stopped the server and restart it

Comment: I noticed you are using more than one module in your project? you might have to put another field in ngModule

Comment: you might have to put exports: [CountdownModule]